# Induction to relate the finite sizes of unions and cartesian products of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question instructs the following:

Prove that for finite sets $X$ and $Y$, we have $|X\times Y|=|X||Y|$ given $|X \cup Y|=|X|+|Y|-|X \cap Y|$

My approach is to fix arbitrary $X$ and induct on $|Y|$. I first map $Y$ to the ordered set of natural numbers with size $|Y|$. The base case is trivial. The inductive step then requires the product of $X\times Y=X\times (Y+ \{ k+1 \} )$ which then I'm stuck.

I don't know how to get unstuck from this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The question is really what properties of $\times$ you are allowed to use in your proof.

Comment: Can you show that $X\times(Y\cup Z) = (X\times Y) \cup (X\times Z)$?

Comment: Oh, so I finally got it with this tip. I split the natural numbers of size n into {1, ..., n-1} and {n} then split the product. Then the rest was showing X x {1, ..., n-1} is disjoint with X x {n}. Thanks.